# Exit powershell script when another process ends

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to make a powershell script to exit simultaneously with notepad. The script should do file backups in the background, so it runs with `while(1)`. I subscribe to `exited` event of notepad process, but `exit` command doesn't seem to work in `Action` block. Nothing happens when I close notepad.

```
$gameRunning = Get-Process notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($gameRunning) {
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject ($gameRunning) -EventName exited -Action {exit} -SourceIdentifier NotepadRunning
}
else {
Write-Host "Game not running."
}

while(1)
{}
```

Any idea how to make it exit from Action scope?

Comment: Well, it blocks the process, and I need it to do file backups in the background.

Comment: Then you better to check `$gameRunning.HasExited` in safe to interrupt points. Otherwise you are risking to interrupt your background backup in undetermined state.

Comment: Thank you, fair point, I will give it a thought too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Environment.Exit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Register-ObjectEvent $gameRunning -EventName Exited -Action {[Environment]::Exit(0)} -SourceIdentifier NotepadExited
```